# Objective-C getting data from a web page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I looked around but I could not find quite the solution to my problem anywhere.

The thing is I would like to get the data that is on a webpage of mine. For example, the content of my web page is "4|3|6" and I would like to have an array with 4,3,6.

I may say something stupid there but I don't really know if my page is XML or HTML, because when I check the source code it just shows "4|3|6" for example.

So is there any way to do this or am I going to have to look into parsers ? And also, how to know of what type my page is ? (it's name is typically "http://example.aspx?value=x" )

I know a lot of questions were asked about this and I apologize if I missed the one with my answer in it.

If it helps, here are the info on the page:

type: text/plain
Encoding: UTF-8

EDIT: So after trying Alex's version, it seems I can't get to retrieve the data. I think the problem is to get the NSString from the data, which is that line:

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This line doesn't give me a crash, but when I try to display it using
    label.text=datastring;

it doesn't display anything. And when I try to assign an NSArray from datastring using the @"|" separator, and try for example to display the first item of that NSArray, it gives me that error about index being out of bounds.

I am not at work right now so I can't really test this but thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source code is just “4|3|6” it’s plain text. You can download it using `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"…"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Then you can create a string from the data and parse it:

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSArray *components = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
[dataString release];
```

Now you’ll have the components in the resulting array. I’m assuming the data is encoded in ASCII, which might not be the case. And the download is synchronous, which means it will block the current thread. If you’re running the code on the main thread, you might want to dispatch it to a background thread so that you don’t block the UI. But that’s to worry about later, just get it working first.

---

As for the asynchronous download, I don’t like the asynchronous `NSURLConnection` interface, as it’s quite a lot of work for what it does. It’s a pity that `NSURLConnection` does not support blocks. You can find some `NSURLConnection` extensions with blocks on the web, but that means relying on third-party code, which carries its own possible problems. One easy way to get the download happening in background is this:

```
- (void) performDownload
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSData *downloadedData = /* synchronous NSURLConnection */;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDidFinish:)
        withObject:downloadedData];
    [pool drain];
}

- (void) downloadDidFinish: (NSData*) data {
    NSLog(@"Data ready: %@", data);
}

- (void) startDownload {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performDownload) withObject:nil];
}
```

But you should learn about threading, run loops and autorelease pools before you start using this code, so that you know what you are doing.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ! And I'm not sure I understood what you said about blocking the UI... Could you explain a bit ?

Comment: basically because the download happens all in the same method unlike my solution, it means that you can't do anything with the app till it's done (the download completes)

Comment: It’s a long story to explain this properly. [Google a bit](http://www.google.com/search?q=nsurlconnection+synchronous+asynchronous+blocking) and learn about Cocoa run loops and the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: Alright... Well I'll look into changing that after a while. For now I'll use this as a temporary solution because it's going to be at max 31 numbers, so I guess it's not going to take long... Or is it ?

Comment: It could take long, for example on a spotty connection. One of the reasons networking is hard is that you have to plan for the worst case all the time. But of course you can simply get it all working now and return to the details in the next iteration. (There’s also error handling to be taken care of…)

Answer (score 3):

Download the text using NSURLConnection - see this [sample code by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Your download method will look something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://example.aspx?value=x""];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

You then buffer the data in an NSMutableData instance - the Apple code explains this really well.

Once you have it, it's really easy to parse.

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Comment: Hello Alex, 
I tried your method; in my viewDidLoad method, I added a test "label.text=xx" and then the whole connection procedure that is on Apple and that you described. The test label renaming works as long as the whole thing is in commentary, and doesn't work when it's not...
Do you need my exact code ? Shall I put it in another method than viewDidload ? Thanks for your help and have a good day!

Comment: sorry what do you mean by 'as long as the whole thing is in commnetary' - do you mean as long as it's commented out? - if so what code do you comment out?

Comment: well basically I comment out everything from "NSURLRequest" up to the declaration of myArray... what I mean is as long as it's commented out, the application will indeed rename my label.

Comment: By the way after doing some more testing, the app blocks only at the last line, which is for me: label.text=datastring;

This is how I declared my datastring: datastring=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receiveddata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Hello Alex, any news ? Sorry if I seem too pushy

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your question... please edit your original question to provide more detail

Comment: OK I edited my question now; but I don't want to take too much of your time and if you still don't understand my question then I might as well drop it for the moment. Thanks for your time in that case !

Comment: Hello Alex, just bringing some news... Apparently the problem comes earlier than my datastring declaration. my if (theConnection) is triggered even when i'm not connected to internet, so I guess the problem is elsewhere. I'll keep looking.